# draw(_ rect: CGRect) not drawing above certain size

Tags: ios, swift, drawrect

I have a custom `UIView` subclass inside a `UIScrollView` that (among other things) overrides

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        ...
    }
}
```

and (minimal example):

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    print(rect)
    UIColor.white.set() // it has a dark background
    UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 10, height: 10)).stroke()
}
```

Drawing works fine for “smaller” sizes of the view, but above a certain limit nothing draws anymore.

It renders fine for the rects

```
(0.0, 0.0, 79.5, 7458.5)
(0.0, 0.0, 228.5, 7458.5)
(0.0, 0.0, 149.0, 7738.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 429.0, 7738.0)
```

But fails for the rects

```
(0.0, 0.0, 89.5, 8381.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 257.0, 8381.0)
```

There is no error message or warning. Nothing that would let me know what fails and why. The `UIScrollView` is still scrollable. Its contents are just empty.

This is happening in a simulated 5th generation iPad and the simulated iPad Pro 9.7".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `draw` is only meant as custom drawing for small views and not huge canvases. However I think this point of failure should be documented somewhere. Making the canvas even larger will result in a `ignoring bogus layer size` warning.

To solve this problem one should either consider

- not using draw
- using a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView` to load and unload the huge layer bit by bit.